# Android 7 Custom Notification - How to show app name and expand/collapse arrow

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-7.0-nougat

My notification is currently a totally custom layout, as Spotify's used to be:

[image]

But I would like to show the app icon, name, and expand/collapse arrow as native Android 7 notifications now do. **How do you get it to show the title and expand/collapse arrow, as Spotify now does?**

[image]
[image]

I'm assuming it's still a custom layout. If not, how do you make custom buttons on a native layout? I know how to use the quick reply bar or inboxStyle, but those don't allow icons.

Thanks

Comment: That's not a custom notification, just a [MediaStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html) notification. Is there a reason you can't use that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#custom

Comment: Oh wow. I did not know MediaStyle was a thing! Thanks ianhanniballake. Also, CommonsWare thank you, whether I decide to go with MediaStyle or not I think that decoratedCustomView is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a custom notification - it is a standard [MediaStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html) notification as explained in the [Using MediaStyle notifications guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice.html#mediastyle-notifications).

If you find you *do* need a custom notification, you can also use the [DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle.html) if you want to maintain the artwork style and automatic resizing used in `MediaStyle` notification.